# Prove that $2\cosh \left(\frac{1}{2} a\right) \sin \left(\frac {1}{2} \alpha\right) = 1.$

Tags: hyperbolic-functions, noneuclidean-geometry

Suppose a hyperbolic equilateral triangle has side $a$ and angle $\alpha$.Prove that  $$2\cosh \left(\frac{1}{2} a\right) \sin \left(\frac {1}{2} \alpha\right) = 1.$$

Comment: @Rammus I saw from a similar problem I can prove this statement by starting with 1/sinh a = sin( $\alpha$/2 ) /sinh (a/2) but I don't know how to explain why it is 1/sinh a...or i guess in other words why is $\alpha$=$\pi$/2.

Comment: For an hyperbolic triangle ABC cosh(c) = cosh(a) cosh(b) - sinh(a) sinh( b) cos(alpha). Now if a=b=c you have a Relatisideonship between cos(alpha) and the side a. You can have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines